# Detecting type of validation error in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and the following works but it doesn't seem very 'Laravel' to me - I just need to detect which validation rule the message refers to (required,email,unique etc):

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    {{ $errors->first('email') }}
    @if (strpos($errors->first('email'), 'has already been taken'))
        {{ HTML::link('password', 'Need a reminder?', array(), FALSE); }}
    @endif
@endif
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Validator in L4 now has a `failed()` method that gives you all your failed rules.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Great, thanks. How would I access that in the view though? At present I have Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::only('email'))->withErrors($user->errors); Would I just redirect with the with() method and pass an array of both errors and failed rules?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, would would do something like this (depending on how it is configured)

**Controller**

```
public function store()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
                      'name' => 'Dayle',
                      'email' => 'required|min:5'
                   ));

    if ($validator->passes())
    {
         // Redirect to success page or something
    }

    return Redirect::back()
             ->withInput()
             ->withErrors($validator)
             ->withFailed($validator->failed())
}
```

then in your view

**View**

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    The specific email rule that failed was: {{ $failed['email'] }}
@endif
```